# How to render Django template after ajax call

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am Building a application that renders a group of cards based on options clicked by user,
I am using ajax on option click so that cards appear without page reload, but the problem is I cannot render the cards into my page, I am passing calculated values to frontend as django context using `return render(request,'base.html',{'context':context})`

Ajax:

```
<script>
function sendData(date){
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST", 
    url: "",
    data: {
      date : date,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
      click:'click'
    },

    });

    return false;
}
</script>
```

view.py:

```
def datepicker(request):
    if 'click' in request.POST:
        return render(request,'datepicker.html',{'dates':availabe_dates,'time':time})
    
    return render(request,'datepicker.html',{'dates':availabe_dates,'time':['choose a date']})
```

I have tried giving:

```
<div class="card-body">
 {% for t in time %}
    <p>{{t}}</p>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Only `choose a date` is shown instead of cards. I am sure that `if 'click' in request.POST:` is runned as I have tried giving some print statements

I have tried returning `jsonResponse` and here is its output `{time:Array(14)}`

Please Help as I am new to Ajax and Django

Comment: Ajax not refresh the page or a perticular html elemnt if you want to update data or want to render a card you have to manually append card element with data coming from backend

Comment: When i use `JsonResponse` i have my data in here `success: function(data)` but i dont know how to append it to card

Comment: Can you log your JsonResponse in console of your browser and put that response in your question by making [edit]

Comment: hey, I have updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Method:**

You can return dictionary as response and populate it in jQuery like this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def datepicker(request):
    if 'click' in request.POST:    
        return JsonResponse({'dates':availabe_dates,'time':time})
```

and in ajax success:

```
<script>
function sendData(date){
  $.ajax({
    // rest of the code
    success: function(response){
      $.each(response.time, function (t) {
         $(".card-body").append(t);
      });
    }    
    });

    return false;
}
</script>
```

**Second Method:**

You can return html from view and add that in ajax success method like this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def datepicker(request):
    if 'click' in request.POST:
        
        html = render_to_string('datepicker.html', {'dates':availabe_dates,'time':time})
        return JsonResponse(html, safe=False)
```

and in ajax:

```
<script>
function sendData(date){
  $.ajax({
    // rest of the code
    success: function(response){
      $(".card-body").html(response);
    }    
    });

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: The second method is by far the simplest approach I've tried implementing, and so far the only successful too. Thanks for posting!